# Hashing password by bcrypt

Tags: node.js, sqlite, bcrypt

I am trying to hash a password using sqlize databaze and bcrypt.

I have initialized password attribute

```
    password:{
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        allowNull:false,
        validate:{
            len:[1,100]
        },
        set: function(value){
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync( value, salt );
            this.setDataValue('password', value );
            this.setDataValue('salt',salt);
            this.setDataValue('password_hash',hashedPassword);
        }
    }
```

but it keeps throwing error

> data and salt arguments required

I have checked up documentation and syntax is correct.
I have not found anything about this error.

Why does it keep complaining about it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the error, but a couple notes about your code: 1) Why are you using `setDataValue( 'password', value );`? The point of hashing is so that you don't end up storing the plaintext password anywhere. 2) Why are you using genSalt*Sync* and hash*Sync*? It seems like a bad, and weird, idea to block the thread for all users when hashing one password. 3) You don't need to call genSalt at all (sync or not), if you pass `null` as the salt for `hash` the bcrypt module will generate the salt for you.

Comment: this is not real world application , i am just realning to work with it and get stuck on this error , but thanks for suggestions i appreciate it and will keep it in mind.

Comment: Have you tried logging `console.log( value );` to make sure it is not `undefined` ? I have a suspicion that you might have an error somewhere else that is causing `undefined` to show up there.